# I've got a Button with image and text - how to give the text itself padding?

Tags: winforms, button, padding

To begin with, I'll show an image of the current display;

[image: description]

You see how the (System.Windows.Forms.)Button's image is placed somewhat correctly, yet the text has no correct left-padding.

How can I give the text of the Button about 30px padding from the left?
I've tried changing the Button's Padding itself, but it changes both the text and the image's padding.

Thanks,

~ Tgys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `TextImageRelation` property:

```
button1.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
```